# AWS Security and Identity Limits: 10 policies is too low in my application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-iot

I'm developing a simple product that will have 10 inputs and 10 outputs, i.e. 20 resources. 
One or more users will be authorized to access a subset of those 20 users.

For example, user1 is authorized to access (I1-I4, O1-O4) of dev1 and (I1-I2,O5-O6) of dev2. user2 is authorized to access (I3-I7,O2-O6) of dev1 and (I1-I8,O1-O8) of dev3. And so on.

I'm thinking how to organize the policies to attach to users, that will be authenticated as Cognito identities.

My first approach is to create 20 policies for each device, one policy for each resource. PolicyDev1_I1, PolicyDev1_I2, and so on. However in this case the maximum number of policies that can be attached to a single Cognito Identity can be exceeded. In the example above, user1 should have 12 policies (8 for dev1 and 4 for dev2).

Is there a better strategy for my application?